# Redirect after PHP Login

Tags: php

I have a subdomain

accounts.mysite.com

What i want is one login panel for that subdomain, then after a user logs in it directs them to their own page (and stops them from viewing 'other account' pages).

So when they go to accounts.mysite.com that is the login page. User logs in using specific name, pass. After successful login directed to their accounts page but blocks all other pages.

Here is what I have so far

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="******"; // Mysql username
$password="*******"; // Mysql password
$db_name="medpro_test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file 
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header('Location: user.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']); 
}

else {
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I am a noob so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also, have you considered using a PHP framework to help you with your application structure?  (Which includes login/account type of things, as well.)  Here is a list of popular PHP frameworks if you decide to use one in the future: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP

Comment: I can't understand why people are still bothering to learn to use `mysql_*` functions. Learn PDO people, it's better!

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks bad.
`session_register("myusername");` - This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0.
Move your database config to another file.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="******"; // Mysql username
$password="*******"; // Mysql password
$db_name="medpro_test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name
```

Use header location http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
to move user to the link.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, it is common practice to reduce code snippets to their bare minimum.  I would rather he NOT start posting complete sets of files with separate configs.

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to get rid of your current PHP book and find yourself a modern one, at least published in the current century.
2. Then rewrite your session code according to [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)
3. then use [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set up a session domain.

Answer (score 0):

Include a file at the top of every file that should be blocked that contains something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id']) {
    header('Location: user.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']); 
    exit;
}
```

This will redirect the user to user.php everytime they try to visit another file.

Edit: And don't forget to use `session_start()` at the beginning of every request.